# Binding a C++ virtual class for use in Python

Tags: python, c++, swig, ffi, vst

I want to know a way of consuming the VST3 SDK from Python. In its essence, the VST3 architecture mimics COM.

My end goal is using the `GetPluginFactory` exported by a VST3 plugin in Python. This function returns a pointer to a C++ virtual class. *I am not sure how this even works across different compilers, because C++ doesn't have a standardized ABI.*

A host and plugin then communicate with each other by querying available "interfaces". I want to know how I can implement the host part in Python. I have used ctypes to mimic a virtual class via a `Structure`, but it doesn't work and useless, since a class has a vtable member and I am not sure how a C++ class looks like in C.

SWIG keeps popping up when I try to search for a solution. So is SWIG, the way to go? If yes, how?

I don't have any code, because all I tried till now results in memory violation errors.

Comment: On any given platform, C++ absolutely does have a standardized ABI, at least for virtual class interfaces.  That's what allows COM and CORBA to work.  The first thing in an object is a vtable, which is just a list of function pointers, each of which accepts the object as its first parameter.

Comment: @TimRoberts These virtual classes aren't completely virtual, they do have a GUID stored in them, although I am not entirely sure its accessible over the DLL boundary

Comment: If a virtual class contains state, it follows the vtable pointer(s).

Comment: What exactly is a virtual class? I could guess what you mean, but still, I haven't heard that term in the context of C++.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt virtual class in this context is like a COM interface. In VST3, every virtual class (interface) derives off of `FUnknown` (similar to COM `IUnknown`). VST3 doesn't use the COM architecture as it is cross platform at all and many people are confused about this as well.

Comment: @TimRoberts And how might I access this vtable? I found [this](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/942922-virtual-pointer-accessing-vtable-class-inside-program), is this it?

Comment: If you have the address of an object, the first thing at that address is the vtable pointer.  Any member variables follow that pointer.  https://shaharmike.com/cpp/vtable-part2/

Comment: @TimRoberts that's really helpful. Pointer magic!

Comment: I have started to make a small repository of swig examples. The interfaces that I wrap here could be useful for you. https://github.com/JensMunkHansen/swig-examples/tree/main/python/abstract_cpp